# Python .pkl file

Tags: python, pickle

I have a pickle file, it's the first time I work with this kind of file and I'm trying to plot something using the data contained in it.

This is my script:

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import glob
import numpy as np

BASEDIR = '/home/paola/Scrivania/Prova/Python/BSRT/'

def ReadProfilesDF(fin):
    profdf = pd.read_pickle(fin)
    # print profdf.keys()

    print 'Beam : {}. - Plane = {} '.format(np.unique(profdf['beam']), np.unique(profdf['plane']))
    print 'Bunches : {} '.format(np.unique(profdf['bid'].values))
    print 'Timestamps : {}'.format(np.unique(profdf['tsutc'].values))
    return profdf

fname = 'BSRTS.pkl'

fin = '{}{}'.format(BASEDIR, fname)
print 'Input filename {}'.format(fin)
profdf = ReadProfilesDF(fin)

profdf.shape

profdf.head()

selrows = profdf[(profdf['plane'] == 'atH') & (profdf['beam'] == 'atB1') & (profdf['bid'] == 0 )]
selrows.shape
np.unique(selrows['rec'])
selrows.set_index(['tsutc'])
selrows.head()
t1 = pd.Timestamp('2018-07-30 21:14', tz='UTC')
t2 = pd.Timestamp('2018-07-30 21:20', tz='UTC')
selrows2 = selrows[(selrows['tsutc'] > t1) & (selrows['tsutc'] < t2)]
selrows2.head()
selrows2.shape
np.unique(selrows2['rec'])
selrows2[selrows2['rec'] == 0].plot(x='x',y='y')
selrows3 = selrows2[selrows2['tsutc'] == pd.Timestamp('2018-07-30 21:14:00.079976475', tz='UTC')]
np.unique(selrows3['rec'])
selrows3.head()
selrows3.plot(y='x')
```

When I run the script, it returns me this *error*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ReadBSRTProfRecords_toPaola.py", line 109, in <module>
    selrows2[selrows2['rec'] == 0].plot(x='x',y='y')
  File "/home/paola/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 2941, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/home/paola/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1977, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/home/paola/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1804, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/home/paola/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 258, in generate
    self._compute_plot_data()
  File "/home/paola/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 373, in _compute_plot_data
    'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Can someone help me to understand which problem there is, please?

Comment: at what point is your dataframe still valid? it doesn't look like its a problem with pickle

Comment: It looks like it is empty, but if try to print all the columns, I can see that there are data between this two timestamps: '2018-09-13 10:02:01' and '2018-09-13 10:51:22', so the timestamp that I have selected falls in this range

Comment: how do `selrows`, `selrows2` and `selrows3` look? maybe you haven't renamed the columns correctly and it doesn't know columns x and y

Comment: That is the problem, I can't print them, since the error in the script is before, and it's related to the function, in particular it's on `profdf = pd.read_pickle(fin)`. But I expect that the the name of the colums should be that ones since I haven't changed them, and two days ago I was able to run a simpler script (that now I don't know why but it doesn't works) that printed the name of the columns and they were like the ones I used.

Comment: sorry, but from what I can see the error is  at `selrows2[selrows2['rec'] == 0].plot(x='x',y='y')`

Comment: Yes, sorry I've to explain my self better. If I try to do `print 'rows = ',selrows`, it prints `rows = Empty DataFrame`. In addition I menaged to print the name of the colums and this is the result: `Columns: [x, y, rec, plane, bid, timestamp, tsutc, beam]`.
Instead the error about which I was speaking in the previous comment is related to the simplier script. But don't take it into account, I was makng confusion.